# Parse query Javascript - "contains" on relational data

Tags: javascript, parsing

Consider I have an object A having pointer to object B.
Object B has a property "title" in it.
I want to query on object A with a string which is contained in title of object B.
Something like

```
var query1 = new Parse.Query("objectA");
query1.include("objectB");
query1.contains("objectB.title", anyQuery);
query.find({
          success: function(obj){
     },
     error: function(obj, error) {    
     }
});
```

"anyQuery" here can be any string entered by a user in search field. Consider a user inputs "Mary" as query I should get all objectA related to objectB having title containing "Mary" in it. For example "Maryland".
Basically in simple words I want to execute a like query on related data in parse.

### Edit

Thank you for the reply. I read the documentation at https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-relational. I would like to extend my question. I want to use the query formed by matchesQuery in an or condition what I have done in my code is below but I get no results:

```
if(filterQuery) {
            var Organization = Parse.Object.extend("Organization");

            //LIKE QUERIES
            var nameLikeQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
            nameLikeQuery.contains("nameLc", filterQuery);  

            var phoneLikeQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
            phoneLikeQuery.contains("phone", filterQuery);      

            var emailLikeQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
            emailLikeQuery.contains("username", filterQuery);

            var organizationMatchQuery = new Parse.Query(Organization);         
            organizationMatchQuery.contains("titleLc", filterQuery);    

            var userOrganizationQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
            userOrganizationQuery.matchesQuery("organization", organizationMatchQuery);

            var userQuery1 = new Parse.Query.or(nameLikeQuery, phoneLikeQuery);
            var userQuery2 = new Parse.Query.or(emailLikeQuery, userQuery1);

            userQuery = new Parse.Query.or(userQuery2, userOrganizationQuery);
        } else {
            userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        }       
        if(type != "ALL") {
            userQuery.equalTo("userType", type);
        }
        userQuery.include("organization");
        userQuery.descending("createdAt");
        userQuery.find();
```

Comment: What are you comparing `objectB.title` to?

Comment: Oops! Sorry. Its query1.contains("objectB.title", anyQuery);
But this doesn't work. 
I want to know the right syntax for the same. Please help me with the same.

Comment: Edit your question to make it accurate then, but also tell us what `anyQuery` is or means.

Comment: I have edited my question. I hope it is understandable now. Sorry for bad question structure.

Comment: This use case appears well documented under relational queries in the parse documentation. https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-relational See `matchesQuery`

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Chris, this scenario is well documented under Relational Queries here:

https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-relational

So for your particular needs it would look like:

```
var objectBQuery = new Parse.Query("objectB");
objectBQuery.contains("title", anyString);
var objectAQuery = new Parse.Query("objectA");
objectAQuery.matchesQuery("objectB", objectBQuery);
objectAQuery.find().then(function (list) {
    // use list
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```